# How do I get a diamond on Teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, moderator-tools

I signed up for Teams SE and I am trying to access the moderator tools. Are there such tools for moderation as there are on other SE sites?
https://stackoverflow.com/c/out-of-the-box/questions

Comment: What kind of moderation tools precisely? Do you mean review queues?

Comment: @Stijn all of them

Comment: Well, I assume you don't have access to the /tools page (called "Moderation Tools") on any of the communities you're currently a member of? If you can clarify your request a bit, perhaps people can point you to existing features, or employees can tell you which are currently being developed.

Comment: @Stijn  What can you do at 100k rep or as an employee?

Comment: @Muze Check out the privs page. That tells you everything you can do as a normal non-diamond non-employee user. Speaking only about non-beta sites: The powers mostly cap out at 20K, with some relatively tame additional data at 25K, and the ability to earn more close and delete votes up to 30k (I think), and flags up to 38Kish, though there are faster an easier ways to earn more flags. And that’s it. Beyond those boundaries, rep earns you no additional abilities. None. To become a mod you have to be elected or installed, and to become an employee you have to get hired. That’s it.

Comment: @DanBron how do I get diamond on TEAMS.SE?

Comment: @Muze teams don't have "diamonds"... if you're the admin - or someone who is admin on the team grants you admin then you get a "hexagon" thing... It mostly just grants you full edit/closing/delete privs edit/delete comments etc...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't.

There are no diamond moderators on Teams. Just regular users and admins (indicated by the hexagonal blob).

Admins are the people who set up the team and pay the money so I would assume that becoming an admin on a team where you're not the one holding the credit card is quite hard.

As for moderation tools, there are no review queues, no flags, no suspensions and the only close option is "duplicate". As the Team members are expected to ask questions about their Team there isn't really the concept of off topic questions. I would assume that admins can delete anything they don't want on the Team.

Comment: I'd suggest that becoming an admin is quite _easy_ . . . if you [have a credit card](https://stackoverflow.com/teams). ;-)

Comment: @jon I was thinking of the case where it's not your team

Comment: @JonEricson I did use a credit card but don't have admin capability.

Answer (score -4):

You already have the diamond, in teams it simply changes the appearance to a hexagon and removes moderation tools.  These features are still there, however - just hidden by the UI.  I've created a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/8949/79306) to show them, and effectively enable moderation features.